# get the username and nickname of any users from active directory

Tags: c#, winforms, networking

I want to get the NickName and username of any users from my active directory how can i do it??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are 2 good articles about C# and active directory:

- [User Management with Active
  Directory—Finding Users](http://en.csharp-online.net/User_Management_with_Active_Directory%E2%80%94Finding_Users)
- [Howto: (Almost) Everything In Active
  Directory via C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx)

A sample of how to access AD:

include System.DirectoryServices.dll reference.

```
DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName);
string userNames="Users :  ";
foreach (DirectoryEntry child in directoryEntry.Children)
{
    if (child.SchemaClassName == "User")
    {
        userNames += child.Name + Environment.NewLine;
        PropertyCollection coll = child.Properties;

        // sample of how to get other values
        object fullName = coll["FullName"].Value;         
        object nickName = coll["OtherName"].Value;         
    }

}
MessageBox.Show(userNames);
```

Here is a list of other properties which values you can get out: [IADsUser Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746340%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @na.farzane: i modified example to show you how to get other vales.

Comment: how can get the username of my user that it's nickname is for example "farzane" from active directory???thanks.

Comment: @na.farzane: take a look at this: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20051106.asp, it explanes how to search ad

Comment: i write your code but the value of fullName is null why:in this line "object fullName = coll["FullName"].Value; "